# How can I safely store and access connection string details?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, database-connection, connection-string

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET MVC web site, and I've come up to a point where I need to integrate a database into the website.

Normally I would simply add the appropriate connection string to the `Web.config` file:

```
<add name="MainDB" 
    connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=TopSecretData; User Id=Joe;
    password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But there's obviously a glaring security flaw if I leave my User Id and password right in the `Web.config`, especially when it's under source control.

**In short: How can I store my connection string details without having it publicly visible?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Best practice is to encrypt your connection strings section.  Use aspnet_regiis.exe, which can be found in various places:

- Start – Visual Studio – Visual Studio Tools – Visual Studio Command Prompt
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (making sure you run as an administrator)

Before:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MainConnectionString" 
 connectionString="data source=Ratbert;database=Sales;username=ASPNET;password=$Double_Rainbow2011" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Run this command:

```
aspnet_regiis –pef connectionStrings c:\PathToWebSite
```

Or, if the above command doesn't work (and you get the aspnet_regiis help text), try

```
aspnet_regiis -pe connectionStrings -app "/" -site 6
```

where the "6" is the ID of the site as reported in IIS.

After:

```
<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
   <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
   <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
     <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
     <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
     </KeyInfo>
     <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>Bf677iFrUFW ... +4n4ZZKXCTUAu2Y=</CipherValue>
     </CipherData>
    </EncryptedKey>
   </KeyInfo>
   <CipherData>
    <CipherValue>UDEZ ...QfXUmM5rQ==</CipherValue>
   </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Now that it is garbled, you can't edit it.
Decrypt like this:

```
aspnet_regiis –pdf connectionStrings c:\PathToWebSite
```

Or

```
aspnet_regiis -pd connectionStrings -app "/" -site 6
```

And then change and re-encrypt.

To read the connection string, use the ConfigurationManager static class.

```
string connStr = 
ConfigurationManager
.Connectionstrings["MainConnectionString"]
.ConnectionString.ToString();

var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);

myConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use whatever integrated security your DB offers, so the password is not an issue. The server gets direct access to the server without having to use a password, but you have to set up a user that only has access from the web server itself.

eg. DBs like MySQL allow you to specify which servers have access to it, restrict access from anywhere else - so a hacker cannot get to your DB except from the web server. This reduces the security surface quite a lot and allows you to store your connection string files in your SCM.

Its still not 100% secure as the hacker could (often easily) hack your web server and view the DB from it. You could store the password elsewhere, but that's just obscuring the problem - if the web server can get access to the password, your hacker can too. (note, other places to store the password include the registry, a separate file like a .udl file or something in /etc). You can secure this file so only the web server user can read it, but a hacked web server can obviously, read it!

So the next step is to abstract the DB connection so it is outside the web server, the usual method is to have a separate process to store your business logic (eg a service) that exposes fixed methods - the web server simply calls the service which does the work and returns data to the web server code.

If a hacker defeats your web server, all they can do is call methods on the service, they would not have direct access to the DB so could not corrupt or modify it. Usually there would be few hints to the hacker of what the service methods were or did, and the service would have a fair amount of validation code to all inputs so a hacker-created message would (hopefully) be rejected. (use timestamps, counters, etc to try to defeat custom-crafted messaged to the service).

This is the approach we used for a high-security system (there's a lot more you can do to secure each segment of this chain using standard OS security mechanisms). The reasons for doing this became very clear to us once our security chap demonstrated a IIS hack that gave him a remote shell with admin privileges. Whatever you do to secure your configs on the web server is pointless if a hacker gets that. (and it was trivially easy to do - since fixed, but there are 0-day exploits being found all the time)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you wanna look into encrypting your connection string:
http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/how-to-encrypt-connection-string-in-webconfig/ 
(article is a bit old)

Answer (score 1):

Common approaches include [encrypting the web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx) and [storing the connection strings in the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649224.aspx).

The second link is a part of a much larger article covering how to properly secure an ASP.NET application.  It was written for WebForms, but the principles are the same.  It's a good read and much of it still applies today, even if it is a bit old.

Answer (score 1):

You could store Encrypted Connection strings in cache. The Cache server is on another server on purpose (This communication can be restricted to 1 port and IP address making far harder to be hacked). This will get the connection string completely off the web server and even if a hacker gets access to the cache they are encrypted. The key is the loading of the strings into cache and that can be done remotely, so those connection strings are never written to the hard drive of the server. The code only decrypts the connection strings as needed and never holds on to those unecrypted strings in a variable.