# Can I hack into a website using its IP address and connection string in asp.net?

Tags: security

Lets say the IP address of a website abcd.com is 258.23.45.32.
And I used the connection string in asp.net as 
  connectionString="Data Source=258.23.45.32;Initial Catalog=Login;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=passwordgoeshere; providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

And every time I change password for the connection string dynamically and test if the connection is working or not. This would be brute password hack attack but will this approach work?
I was just curious before buying myself a SQL Server Windows hosting package as Linux ones use MySQL.
If the connection works then I can get the databases names and all other info anyways.

I want to know if this technique works from any pc to any website(which I doubt).
Please shed some light on this.

Comment: Obviously a brute force login attack will succeed sooner or later (much later) unless the server is secured against that. This has absolutely nothing to do with what operating system or database system the server uses. So the question is: is the server secured against such attacks or not.

Comment: @arkascha Yes you can say that that is the question but I want to know if we can hack into any website by using above code? I found one article that says to encrypt web.config connectionstring tag here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230864/how-can-i-safely-store-and-access-connection-string-details

Comment: ? I answered that, didn't I? Obviously you can _not_, since every server administrator obviously tries to secure his system against such primitive attacks. Otherwise we would not have any web servers, so no web, right?

Comment: Seriously though, brute forcing _is_ possible, but you're going to be waiting a _long_ time for any result. Windows or Linux hosting is pretty much irrelevant, it's your web-site code that will ultimately make the difference as to how easily someone can gain access to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking a really broad question so let's break things down. Your question is pertaining to data tampering with the strings being given to the server, by a client. Your variables are now separated with the semicolon:

```
Data Source=258.23.45.32;
Initial Catalog=Login;
Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=sa;
Password=passwordgoeshere;
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

To answer your initial question: *every time I change password for the connection string dynamically and test if the connection is working or not. This would be brute password hack attack but will this approach work* The answer to this is, yet it is a variation of a brute force attack although a brutally clumsy and slow one, and it ***may*** work if a server is misconfigured.

You then state/ask *If the connection works then I can get the databases names and all other info anyways.* Again, it all depends on how the database is configured. Suppose the user doesn't have privileges to a **SPECIFIC** database, then you will NOT be able to access anything. You would need to escalate your privileges.

You then asked: *I want to know if this technique works from any pc to any website(which I doubt).* This will work across any machine to any website. There is no mechanism for a server to determine whether or not an initiated connection is trusted. What developers ***can*** do is configure a server to alert, block, drop on unauthorized attempts.